# Flash Builder 4.6 Mobile Layout

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, actionscript, builder

Can you help me with this flex layout. I have to make something similar and I need some tips to make it, not exactly code. The buttons in the grid are tappable and can change the view. Thanks. :)

http://a848.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/061/Purple/v4/65/e4/c1/65e4c13b-cd19-8d23-f30c-10f29705097d/mzl.acytcmdz.320x480-75.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use a [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html), or [Group](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Group.html), with a [TileLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/TileLayout.html).